# In MVC3 how to save more models at time from a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my MVC3 project I have a model like this

```
Public Class Description

    Public Property DescriptionId As Integer

    <DisplayName("Product Title"), Required(ErrorMessage:="A Product Title is required"), StringLength(160)>
    Public Property ProductTitle As String

    <DisplayName("Product Description"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)>
    Public Property ProductDescription As String

End Class
```

From a View like the following

```
@ModelType MyProject.Description

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Create"
End Code

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
    @<fieldset>
        <legend>Description</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.ProductTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.ProductTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ProductTitle)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.ProductDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.ProductDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ProductDescription)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
End Using

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I can create one new Description at time, however is there a method to insert more Descriptions at time (for example five descriptions) and how to get them in the Controller Action?

Comment: Use a Grid, like any [JQuery Grid](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-grids/), instead of a form with fields ([JQuery UI Grid](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/34246941/Grid) is a very good one), and a List<MyProject.Description> as the model

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure VB.net syntax, I provide c# version of it.

1. Use collection in your view model, like `List<String> ProductDescription {get;set;}`
2. In view, render descriptions manually,avoid EditorFor

   `for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProductDescription.Count;i++ )
   {
       @Html.TextBox("ProductDescription[" + i + "]")
   }`
3. When posting back, use Description as your action argument.